# Docker in Docker permissions error

Tags: jenkins, docker

I have a docker in docker setup for CI. Essentially, the machine has a jenkins CI server on it that uses the same machines docker socket to create nodes for CI.

This was working great until I recently updated docker. I've identified the issue, but I can't seem to figure out the right magic to get it working.

```
host $ docker exec -it myjenkins bash
jenkins@container $ docker ps
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon 
socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.26/containers/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

host $ docker exec -it -u root -it myjenkins bash
root@container $ docker ps 
... docker ps from host container yay! ...
```

So here's what I surmise. I have access to the host docker socket from within the container, but I can't seem to give permission to the jenkins user.

I've added the docker group, and also added the jenkins user to the docker group. But I still get the same error. I've restarted a whack of times so, I'm kind of at a loss for what to do next.

Is there a way to force permissions for a user on a particular socket?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try the same thing with a privileged container (as root inside)?

Comment: If you look at my question where I present console. I showed that I tried as the jenkins user, and then again as the root user of the container. The root user has access, the jenkins user does not.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you try the same thing with a *privileged* container (as jenkins inside)

Comment: And the same thing with ` --userns=host` ?

Comment: It is a privliedged container. I'm not sure how to user `--userns=host` how would I specify that using docker-compose.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to map the gid of the docker group on your host to the gid of a group that jenkins belongs to inside your container. Here's a sample from my Dockerfile of how I've built a jenkins slave image:

```
ARG DOCKER_GID=993

RUN groupadd -g ${DOCKER_GID} docker \
  && curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh \
  && apt-get -q autoremove \
  && apt-get -q clean -y \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/apt/*.bin 

RUN useradd -m -d /home/jenkins -s /bin/sh jenkins \
  && usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

The 993 happens to be the gid of docker on the host in this example, you'd adjust that to match your environment.

---

*Solution from the OP:*
If rebuilding isn't a possibility you can set the docker group accordingly in using root and add the user. If you tried this before you may have to delete the group on the slave (`groupdel docker`):

```
docker exec -it -u root myjenkins bash
container $ groupadd -g 993 docker
container $ usermod -aG docker jenkins
```

Comment: OK. I see. On the host docker is 999. In the slave docker is 1001. So what you're saying is that I need to make sure that gid on slave is same as host? Do you think I can get away with just editing `/etc/group`?

Comment: The gid on the docker.sock file needs to also be a gid of the user inside the container. You can create any group inside the image with this id, and add Jenkins to that group. Changing the /etc/group on the host won't work without fixing permissions on the files too.

Comment: Excellent excellent excellent. I'm going to update your answer with my fix.

Comment: @BMitch you are really docker guru. superb!. I'm fighting with that problem more than three hours. Finally your answer put full stop :-)

Comment: When I mount docker.sock to the container, ls -l shows nobody nogroup. What am I missing?

Comment: What's the UID/GID on the host? And what's the UID/GID in the container? And have you configured userns?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in other answers, you must ensure that user "jenkins" inside the container has permission to issue Docker commands to the Docker engine on the host via the `/var/run/docker.sock` mount.

An easy way to do this is:

```
$ docker run --rm -d --group-add $(stat -c '%g' /var/run/docker.sock) -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -P myjenkins
```

But beware:

If your Jenkins job has the need to execute Docker build/run commands (e.g., to build a container), this is *not* sufficient. The reason is that the containerized Jenkins will ask the Docker in the host to deploy a Docker agent container and that Docker agent container will face similar "permission errors" when connecting to the Docker daemon on the host.

There is a blog post describing the problem and solution for this at https://blog.nestybox.com/2019/09/29/jenkins.html.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, i've just had to do this :

```
sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker
```

And it worked out

Answer (score 0):

Execute the command with your root user by including sudo in the start.