# AWS Fargate jenkins docker volume mount is not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, jenkins, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I was trying to set up a jenkins docker container in the ECS fargate. But each time the task stops the data will get loss. So, I had attached the jenkins-volume mount option in the container - task definition.

> Container Path - /var/jenkins_home
>
> Source Volume  - jenkins-volume

But after stating the service, I am getting errors,

> touch: cannot touch '/var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log': Permission denied
>
> Can not write to /var/jenkins_home/copy_reference_file.log. Wrong volume permissions?

Comment: It's issue with docker inside docker permission. Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164653/docker-in-docker-permissions-error

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to run jenkins on aws ECS-fargate and mounting the volume on EFS. I resolved this issue by changing the user in my Dockerfile to root.
`USER root`