# Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket

Tags: docker, gradle, docker-compose, daemon

On the [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) (Bionic Beaver) system, I have cloned a project and to run it needs [Gradle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradle), but at running the Gradle command `gradle swiplRun` I get the following error

> Task :dockerRun FAILED
> docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/create?name=swiprolog: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
> See 'docker run --help'.

> Task :dockerRunStatus FAILED
> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.39/containers/swiprolog/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

> FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

To solve it, I tried:

```
sudo groupadd docker
sudo usermod -a -G docker myname
  "and once with"
sudo gpasswd -a myname docker
```

So I can run Docker commands without sudo, but the same error. Also `./gradlew --stop` and logout/login and reboot did not work either.

Is it because of Docker or Gradle?

Comment: Did you try opening new shell? It might be that group membership doesn't apply to your current shell.

Comment: @IgorNikolaev I doubt what you mean by opening a new shell? doesn't the rebooting system count as if a new shell is opened?

Comment: Rebooting should help, I must have missed that you tried to login/logoff. How did you install Docker? I remember installing Docker recently on Ubuntu and it required custom package repository to be added. I think we followed this instruction (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04) and it worked after that.

Comment: Also probably verify that your user had `docker` group assigned after all. It didn't work for us for some reason at first, only after we installed Docker according to the documentation mentioned above.

Comment: Is this a dupe to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42164653/?

Answer (score 12):

Try restarting Docker once:

```
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Then this one to finally solve the problem:

```
sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now try running:

```
docker run hello-world
```

It will pull the image from the [Docker Hub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_(software)#Components) repository and that means your Docker instance is now running properly.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Something is resetting my permissions.

Comment: can you try reinstalling docker ? and then follow this ? @KirkSefchik

Comment: worked on Ubuntu WSL2