# Cannot get access to a Docker socket when running as 'systemd' services

Tags: docker, systemd

I have an application, which I would like to run as systemd user services.

This application can interact with Docker containers, which works when I run the application like `/usr/bin/app` from User `u`.

But when I load the application as a user service, `systemctl enable --now --user app.service`, I get the following error:

```
 time="2023-06-19T14:43:15+02:00" level=error msg="Cannot get containers: could not get containers from Docker (Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get \"http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&limit=0\": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied)"
```

The [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) service is defined as

```
[Unit]
Description=App description
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/app
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Should the service behave like "just" running the application as a binary?

The user is already in the Docker group.

I have looked at:

- [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47854463/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke)
- [Docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54523977/docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socke)

But neither solves my problem.

Comment: Read Mouat blog https://blog.container-solutions.com/running-docker-containers-with-systemd

Comment: @RichardRublev thank you, but this didn't help either had found this blog post also :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was wrong.
Even though the Docker host was set in the environment for the user.
It was not available to the the service.

Therefore in the code of the service I set an environment variable that correctly configured the docker host.
It is not pretty but it works