# sudo/docker not found while running the Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have Jenkins running inside docker on an aws ec2 instance. I am using the following command to bring the Jenkins up:

```
sudo docker run --privileged --name jenkins-master -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -d jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

Following is my JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Docker Permissions") {
        agent any
            steps {
                sh "sudo chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock"
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'maven:3-alpine'
                    args '-v $HOME/.m2:/root/.m2'
                }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn clean package -DskipTests'
            }
        }
        stage('Build') {
        agent none
            steps {
                script {
                    image = docker.build("image11")
                    println "Newly generated image: " + image.id
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the Jenkins job logs, I get `sudo not found` when I run the job. If I remove the first stage 'Docker Permissions' then I start getting following `docker not found`.

> /var/jenkins_home/workspace test@tmp/durable-12345/script.sh: 1:
> /var/jenkins_home/workspace test@tmp/durable-12345/script.sh: docker:
> not found

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to change permissions during your first step.
So you can remove your first stage `Docker Permissions`.

Run your container like this :

```
sudo docker run --name jenkins-master -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -d jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

- You can remove the `--privileged` flag
- You need to share the docker host with your container :
  `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock`
- You also need to share the docker path to your container :
  `-v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker`

See informations on the [docker forum](https://forums.docker.com/t/using-docker-in-a-dockerized-jenkins-container/322/4).

Comment: Thanks. I am getting permission denied now. 

`Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.40/containers/maven:3-alpine/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied`

Comment: You have to add the jnekins user to the docker group. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42168499/7953086

Comment: Do we need to pass the image id here? $(which docker)

Comment: This is the path for the docker host in your local machine.

Comment: I'm receiving below error when I run docker run command. What am I missing?
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/usr/bin/docker': mkdir /usr/bin/docker: read-only file system.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled

Answer (score -1):

In Docker it is not recommended to use "sudo". If you are able to run docker then you can very easily become root. while doing Jenkins up you are already using `--privileged` which should run this command with higher privilege.

Try to remove `sudo` from command and run.

Comment: Thanks. I did. Then I start getting the docker not found error. `/var/jenkins_home/workspace test@tmp/durable-12345/script.sh: 1: /var/jenkins_home/workspace test@tmp/durable-12345/script.sh: docker: not found

`